# Execute animation Only one time at Text field editing

Tags: uitextfield, ios9, uiviewanimation, catransition

I have multiple textfields when i edit the textfield i appear one view using CATransition Animation method. The animation will appear on every textfield editing but my requirement only the first textfield editing otherwise view will appear on the view.
I do the animation like below code

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{


CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[keyBoardView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[keyBoardView addSubview:keyboard];
}
```

how to achieve this any suggestions

Comment: Why not just set a bool flag to true or false depending on the state of the view?